# Seam - how to deatach entity

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0, seam

I'm working on Seam project and have following problem - there is an ajax edit form and many interactions with this form affect (mutate) underlying entity and are changed in db immediately, but I wan't those changes persisted in database only when user will press "save" button. I'm thinking about deataching entity to accomplish this but wonder how (Also looking for smarter solutions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The changes that you are making to an entity are immediately reflected making it synchronized with database. To detach a entity, you can use `entityManager.detach(object)` or `entityManager.clear()`, but that will detach all managed entities.

EntityManager's flush-mode is `FlushModeType.AUTO` by default, instead try `FlushModeType.COMMIT` in which changes are flushed only on explicit commit/flush & then using `entityManager.flush()` to synchronize the persistence context to the underlying database.

Comment: entityManager.detach(object) is maybe a cool thing but is available since java 6, my project uses java 5.

Comment: Try managing transactions manually(BMT), rather then using CMT, so you will be able to persist entity when required after making changes.